# MySQL Query Not Occuring with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I appreciate your responses in advance.

I have several pages of orders that I am dealing with, however I am sure fixing one will provide me with enough knowledge to fix the others. In this case, I will show you the `daytasks.php` section. Basically, I can make function changes to the first line, but the second, third, etc. lines cannot be modified. Using the function buttons does nothing for those lines. `daytasks.php` calls upon `fetchdaytasks.php` to get the information based on date, which calls upon `./functions/additions.js` to perform the Javascript, which calls upon  the functions corresponding script to perform the action requested.

e.g. I have two orders, each in their own separate `<tr>`, I can modify the first row, which is ID #`28` with any of the functions, but the second row, ID #`35` I cannot modify, it will simply not make any changes.

Portion of `daytasks.php`

```
<div class="form-group">  
                <br />
                <center>
                     <div class="input-group"> 
                        <input type="date" id="search_text" name="search_text" />
                    </div>
                    <div id="result"></div>  
                </center>
</div>
```

Portion of `fetchdaytasks.php`

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)  
 {  
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
     {
         $id=$row['id'];
         $orderdate=$row['date'];
         $order=$row['order'];
         $status=$row['status'];
 echo "
                <td><center>$id</center></td>
                <td><center>$orderdate</center></td>
                <td><center>$order</center></td>
                <td><center>$status</center></td>
                <form>
                <td><center><button type='button' name='btn_ship' id='btn_ship' class='btn btn-xs btn-success' data-id='$id'>SHIP</button> <button type='button' name='btn_unship' id='btn_unship' class='btn btn-xs btn-danger btn_delete'>UNSHIP</button> <button type='button' name='btn_bo' id='btn_bo' class='btn btn-xs btn-danger btn_delete'>BACKORDER</button> <button type='button' name='btn_fbo' id='btn_fbo' class='btn btn-xs btn-danger btn_delete'>FBO</button><br />
            <button type='button' name='btn_cancel' id='btn_cancel' class='btn btn-xs btn-danger btn_delete'>CANCEL</button> <button type='button' name='btn_return' id='btn_return' class='btn btn-xs btn-danger btn_delete'>RETURN</button> <button type='button' name='btn_dam' id='btn_dam' class='btn btn-xs btn-danger btn_delete'>DAMAGED</button> <button type='button' name='btn_lost' id='btn_lost' class='btn btn-xs btn-danger btn_delete'>LOST</button></td>
            </form>
            </tr>
            ";
     }
 }
 else
 {
     echo "No Orders For This Date";
 }
```

Portion of `additions.js`

```
    $("#btn_ship").click(function(){
var changeid = $( this ).data('id');    
 var myData={"changeid":changeid};
 $.ajax({
    url : "./functions/shiporder.php",
    type: "POST",
    data : myData,
    success: function(data,status,xhr)
     {
        $("#status_text").html(data);
        $('#changeid').val();
     }
}); 
});
```

`./functions/shiporder.php`

```
<?php  
include_once('/home/brandina/public_html/eldis/config/config.php');
 $changeid = $_POST['changeid'];
 if(mysqli_query($connect, "UPDATE `orders` SET `status`='SHIP' WHERE `id`='$changeid'"))
 ?>
```

Comment: Er... Not sure... Can you be a bit clear.

Comment: Your code is wide open to SQL injections. Use parameterized queries.

Comment: @X.L.Ant at this point I am truly not concerned about SQL injections. This script is being used internally by myself only. Security of the server or this database is not required.

Comment: One quick thing I noticed is your `while` loop doesn't print out an opening `<tr>`, could that be causing any issues?

Comment: @Fanis - in the upper portion of the code it prints the `<tr>` based on some if values that was omitted. Sorry for not including this.

Comment: you can't use `<form>` as sibling of `<td>`...it's invalid html. Table elements have very specific allowed children and browser will move invalid nested tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're printing out rows of orders with buttons in a loop, however the buttons all have the same `id`, whereas HTML elements must have [unique IDs](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#adef-id) within the page if they're assigned one one:

`<button type='button' name='btn_ship' id='btn_ship' class='btn btn-xs btn-success' data-id='$id'>SHIP</button>`

Then you attach an on-click handler via jQuery, but you target the id `btn_ship`, so it only gets attached to the first instance of that element (the first row), so it will only work for that one:

`$("#btn_ship").click(function(){`

I suggest you make the ids unique by appending the `$id` to each one, within the while loop in `fetchdaytasks.php`, instead of printing out:

`<button type='button' name='btn_ship' id='btn_ship' class='btn btn-xs btn-success' data-id='$id'>SHIP</button>`

print out:

`<button type='button' name='btn_ship' id='btn_ship_$id' class='btn btn-xs btn-success' data-id='$id'>SHIP</button>`

and [use the common `name` element](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) of the buttons to attach on-click handlers to each one in `additions.js`, so instead of:

`$("#btn_ship").click(function(){`

do:

`$('input[name="btn_ship"]').click(function(e) {`

Comment: Thanks for providing this information. I am unsure where to make these changes. I understand what you are saying about the `btn_ship` only being attached to the first instance because it does not have a unique ID, but how can I replicate this issue in my code? I appreciate your time!

Comment: I added some more detail on where to edit what in my answer, hope this helps.

Comment: I made the suggested changes and it has now broken the script - it is no longer able to modify the database for any rows. No error messages from what I can see. :(

Comment: To make sure you're seeing all errors, add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and, if you're running it locally, also add `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of all scripts. If you don't have a local development environment and are instead working directly on the production server, prefer instead of `display_errors` to do: `ini_set('log_errors', 1); ini_set('error_log', '/tmp/phperror.log');` - then look at what that file includes.

Comment: sorry for never replying I did not see this. It did work out and has helped me with future projects as well! Thank you!